# Shortest Path between two Trie Nodes

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, performance, sorting

This is a twofold question, because I'm out of ideas on how to implement this most efficiently.

I have a dictionary of 150,000 words, stored into a Trie implementation, here's what my particular implementation looks like: [image: trie-graph]

A user is given a provided with two words. With the goal being to find the shortest path of other english words (changed by one character apiece) from the start word to the end word.

For example:

> Start: Dog
>
> End: Cat
>
> Path: Dog, Dot, Cot, Cat
>
> Path: Dog, Cog, Log, Bog, Bot, Cot, Cat
>
> Path: Dog, Doe, Joe, Joy, Jot, Cot, Cat

---

My current implementation has gone through several iterations, but the simplest I can provide pseudocode for (as the actual code is several files):

```
var start = "dog";
var end = "cat";
var alphabet = [a, b, c, d, e .... y, z];
var possible_words = [];

for (var letter_of_word = 0; letter_of_word < start.length; letter_of_word++) {
  for (var letter_of_alphabet = 0; letter_of_alphabet < alphabet.length; letter_of_alphabet++) {
      var new_word = start;
      new_word.characterAt(letter_of_word) = alphabet[letter_of_alphabet];
      if (in_dictionary(new_word)) {
          add_to.possible_words;
      }
  }  
}

function bfs() {
    var q = [];
    ... usual bfs implementation here ..
}
```

---

Knowns:

- A start word and a finish word
- Words are of the same length
- Words are english words
- It is possible for there to not be a path

---

## Question:

My issue is I do not have an efficient way of determining a potential word to try without brute-forcing the alphabet and checking each new word against the dictionary. I know there is a possibility of a more efficient way using prefixes, but I can't figure out a proper implementation, or one that doesn't just double the processing.

Secondly, should I be using a different search algorithm, I've looked at A* and Best First Search as possibilities, but those require weights, which I don't have.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just a thought: if your words were stored in a graph where each node connects to words differing by one letter (with all edge costs/weights being 1), you could use [Dijkstra's algortihm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path between any two words.

Comment: @TonyD Appreciate that! I'm not opposed to doing that, but if I understand that implementation correctly, instead of having 150,000 entries, I would exponentiate that, as each word would have `(26! * length of word)` possible leaves correct?

Comment: Each word would need to be in a node with a container of links of some kind to other nodes.  The links could be e.g. indices in an array where all the word/nodes are stored, or "pointers" in a language that supports that.  It would also be possible to store a 32-bit integer for each letter in the word, wherein each of the first 26 bits indicated whether there's a word with only that letter changed to 'A'+bit-position (for example, "dog"'s first 32-bit value would have bits on at positions 'B'-'A'=1, 'C'-A'=2, 'F'-'A'=5 etc..

Comment: @TonyD interesting... I like where you're going with that. It is a dictionary after all, which means once the object is created, it wouldn't need to be changed. Could you expand on the 32-bit integer idea? I'm only understanding it partially.

Comment: @TonyD Really appreciate the input Tony, it's looking like I'll have to make a different type of data structure, and your idea is a fantastic place to start!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested in comments, illustrating what I mean by encoding linked words in the bits of integers.

In C++, it might look something like...

```
// populate a list of known words (or read from file etc)...
std::vector<std::string> words = {
    "dog", "dot", "cot", "cat", "log", "bog"
};

// create sets of one-letter-apart words...
std::unordered_map<std::string, int32_t> links;
for (auto& word : words)
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)
    {
        char save = word[i];
        word[i] = '_';
        links[word] |= 1 << (save - 'a');
        word[i] = save;
    }
```

After the above code runs, `links[x]` - where `x` is a word with one letter replaced with an underscore a la `d_g` - retrieves an integer indicating the letters that can replace the underscore to form known words.  If the least significant bit is on, then 'dag' is a known word, if the next-from-least-significant bit is on, then 'dbg' is known word etc..

Intuitively I'd expect using integers to reduce the overall memory used for linkage data, but if the majority of words only have a couple linked words each, storing some index or pointer to those words may actually use less memory - and be easier if you're unused to bitwise manipulations, i.e.:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<const char*>> links;
for (auto& word : words)
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)
    {
        char save = word[i];
        word[i] = '_';
        links[word].push_back(word.c_str());
        word[i] = save;
    }
```

Either way, you then have a graph linking each word to those it can transform into with single-character changes.  You can then apply the logic of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find a shortest path between any two words.

Comment: Wow. That makes much more sense and is incredibly elegant. Thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: @acupajoe: you're welcome.  Good luck with the rest of the implementation.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an update for those that starred this question, I've added a Github repository for an implementation in Javascript for this particular Data-structure.

https://github.com/acupajoe/Lexibit.js

Thank you all for the help and ideas!